Unable to LOAD CSV via https private URL neo4j 5.18
I'm using the below query to load CSV from a private URL, and am enabling imports from files in neo4j.conf:
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true

But this Cypher code:
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://mySample/api/File/DownloadFile/mysample.csv" AS row

fails with the error:

Cypher Neo4j Couldn't load the external resource from URL
https://mySample/api/File/DownloadFile/mysample.csv

stacktraces:
Caused by: org.neo4j.exceptions.CypherExecutionException: Failed to parse query LOAD CSV FROM "https://mySample/api/File/DownloadFile/mysample.csv.
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ast.factory.neo4j.JavaCCParser$.parse(JavaCCParser.scala:61) ~[neo4j-cypher-ast-factory-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.Parse$.process(Parse.scala:38) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.Parse$.process(Parse.scala:31) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.Phase.$anonfun$transform$1(Phase.scala:36) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.helpers.package$.$anonfun$closing$1(package.scala:25) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.helpers.package$.using(package.scala:34) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.helpers.package$.closing(package.scala:25) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.Phase.transform(Phase.scala:35) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.Phase.transform$(Phase.scala:33) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.Parse$.transform(Parse.scala:31) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.phases.PipeLine.transform(Transformer.scala:78) ~[neo4j-front-end-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.CypherParsing.parseQuery(CypherParsing.scala:80) ~[neo4j-cypher-planner-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.router.impl.query.QueryProcessorImpl.parse(QueryProcessorImpl.java:271) ~[neo4j-query-router-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.router.impl.query.QueryProcessorImpl.prepareQueryForCache(QueryProcessorImpl.java:160) ~[neo4j-query-router-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.router.impl.query.QueryProcessorImpl.getFromCache(QueryProcessorImpl.java:144) ~[neo4j-query-router-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.router.impl.query.QueryProcessorImpl.processQuery(QueryProcessorImpl.java:104) ~[neo4j-query-router-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.router.impl.QueryRouterImpl.executeQuery(QueryRouterImpl.java:198) ~[neo4j-query-router-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.router.impl.bolt.QueryRouterBoltSpi$Transaction.executeQuery(QueryRouterBoltSpi.java:162) ~[neo4j-query-router-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.bolt.tx.TransactionImpl.run(TransactionImpl.java:136) ~[neo4j-bolt-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]
at org.neo4j.bolt.protocol.common.fsm.transition.transaction.CreateStatementStateTransition.process(CreateStatementStateTransition.java:48) ~[neo4j-bolt-5.18.1.jar:5.18.1]

Expected behavior
neo4j 5.18 should load the csv file from the given private URL
Actual behavior
Unable load neo4j 5.18 from the given private URL
Note:
Same private URL gets downloaded via accessing the browser.
Also other public csv url's gets loaded from neo4j as well.

Are you saying that you can see the CSV file when navigating to
https://mySample/api/File/DownloadFile/mysample.csv using a browser?

When I hit the url in browser address bar in chrome it gets downloaded the csv. What I want is to load the CSV from the https private url directory

Assuming that the CSV file is on the same computer as the neo4j server, you are using the wrong URI scheme, "https", and you should be using the "file" scheme instead.
For example, if the local file were in the neo4j import directory, then use this clause:
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///mysample.csv" AS row

See the docs here and here for more info.

Thanks for the response @cybersam my expectation is to load the csv directory from given private url. But it isnt happening in neo4j version 5.18
